# Debian Jessie, or any Linux distribution a good way to manage Java versions

Tags: java, linux, version

I have two versions of Java Oracle, java 7 and java 8, and some times openjdk in my debian

```
cat /etc/debian_version
8.1
```

Depending of what I using I need to change from java 8 to Java 7, IE compiling things that doesn't work with 8 (Like play framewrok with some version of javasssist 3.8) or using lambdas or last versions of SBT and Play.

Normaly I have to change always JAVA_HOMDE, and `update-alternatives --config java` `update-alternatives --config javac`, and restart the terminal or the linux session

There is an easy way to make that, now I use sometimes this

```
apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

it works, but I need to restart the session, and it seems no sense to do this with packages. I also look over the internet and there solutions but there are similar to what I did, and also there is some think like rvm in ruby.